# How to integrate XML markers with MarkerCluster?

Tags: xml

I'm having a problem integrating XML markers with MarkerClusterer. 
I need to integrate these two and show only the markers within bounds. I'm able to load the results in the XML to the map, but can not integrate the MarkerClusterer.

```
var customIcons = {
      Commercial: {
        icon: 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/32/Company.png',
      },
      Condo: {
        icon: 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/REALVISTA/project_managment/png/32/agency.png',
      },
      Home: {
        icon: 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/32/Home.png',
      },
      Lot: {
        icon: 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Real-Estate-png/32/Lands.png',
      }
    };


function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ?>, <?php echo $long ?>),
    zoom: <?php echo $zoom ?>,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("mapxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}
```